# How to import a project into Intellij IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to import a GitHub project into Intellij. First I downloaded the project, then I opened Intellij, I clicked on import project then import project from external model (gradle), next, Use auto-import.

Here the owner mentioned that one must select "Use default gradle (recommended)", but I don't find it.

So I selected "use gradle wrapper task configuration" then finish. 
I got this screen.

[image: capture]

[Link to the project](http://github.com/frankandrobot/rapier)

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved.
It was caused by the SDK.
select build.gradle -> build -> build project -> select the JDK as SDK